# What is the probability of getting given number of occurrences with known average outcome

Tags: probability

There are $92000$ random choices. Each one is selection of value $\{0, 1\}$ with given probabilities $\{0.95, 0.05\}$. So on average in series of $92000$ we will get $4600$ values of $1$.

What is the probability that in a sequence of $92000$ choices we will get less than $2300$ values of $1$? How should I approach this problem?

Comment: @JMoravitz are you a genius or something

Comment: See more [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) or various learning websites like [online.stat.psu.edu](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/28/28.1), [probability.oer.math.uconn.edu](https://probability.oer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/2187/2018/01/prob3160ch9.pdf) or others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can estimate this easily by having compared this to a normal
> distribution which this will closely mimic. Your exact distribution is
> binomial with a mean of np=92000⋅0.05−4600 and a variance of
> npq=92000⋅0.05⋅0.95, the standard deviation then being the square root
> of the variance, about 66.1 here. You are then asking for the
> probability of lying at or below almost 35 standard deviations below
> the mean. That is incredibly unlikely, probability less than 10−250.
> More careful tracking of values can get you more specific, I rounded
> several places.

–  JMoravitz  4 mins ago

Comment: At least paraphrase what others say rather than copy-pasting verbatim and not even bothering to format things correctly

Comment: Also, "loose" is like for a rope... the opposite of tight.  A "looser" would be someone who loosens a rope, for example to untie something.  You mean to say *loser*.

Comment: upvoted! no mean to disrespec!

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate this easily by having compared this to a normal distribution which this will closely mimic. Your exact distribution is binomial with a mean of $np=92000⋅0.05=4600$ and a variance of $npq=92000\cdot 0.05\cdot 0.95$, the standard deviation then being the square root of the variance, about $66.1$ here. You are then asking for the probability of lying at or below almost $35$ standard deviations below the mean. That is incredibly unlikely, probability less than $10^{-250}$. More careful tracking of values can get you more specific, I rounded several places.

See more [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) or various learning websites like [online.stat.psu.edu](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/28/28.1), [probability.oer.math.uconn.edu](https://probability.oer.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/2187/2018/01/prob3160ch9.pdf) or others

Comment: To put that probability in perspective, it's about equal to the chance of repeatedly selecting a random atom in the observable universe, and finding that you picked the same atom 4 times in a row.